# Rails: JS Controller Being Called Twice for Some Reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

For some reason when I click on a button, my controller and the resulting jquery function gets called twice. Since the js function being called is toggle, this is a problem as it causes the code to jump in and out of view.

Here is the form:

```
Unseen Notifications: <%=  current_user.notification_unseen %> </div>
                <%= button_to "show", {:action => "seen", :controller=>"notifications"}, :remote => true %>
```

Here is the controller:

```
def seen
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$("div#notifications").toggle();
$("div#count").html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => 'notifications/count')%>");
```

I am at a loss for why on earth this would possibly happen. I have been very careful not to double click and don't know how to prevent it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreicated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a recent problem like this before, when I had 2 jquery libraries included. In particular, check that you only have jquery_ujs.js and not jquery.js. Seems like when you include both of them certain js functions are called twice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I second this motion. Same has happened to me with multiple libraries referenced.

Comment: god bless you benjamin, definitely saved me a day or so there

Comment: I got your point . but when i remove any of these , either ajax / jquery stops working

Answer (score 5):

If Benjamin's suggestion doesn't work, you could go with cheats and hacks and add 1 to some global var on each click (which would happen twice), then use modulus to only trigger your action when (global_counter % 2 == 0).

Just to be clear, this is a terrible solution that you should avoid using if at all possible...

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to rails and had the same problem. It turns out I had:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

In both my view and in application.html.erb. I removed one of them and voila, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running jquery in rails 5.1 and beyond, as rails dropped jquery support and switch to its own ujs, you need to remove //= require rails-ujs from application.js file.

I had the same problem while running latest version of rails, this solved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Michael Mayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831089/7573223)'s and [Benjamin Tan Wei Hao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659245/7573223)'s answers:

it is possible for a second
`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` to get added to the layout (even automatically) when implementing Webpacker. This happened recently, when modernizing an older application that isn't quite ready for Rails 7.

**TL;DR;**

Beware the second `application.js` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the jquery_ujs.js worked for me.

Take a close look at the file **application.html.erb** to see if that is referring to jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js. If so, just take the jquery_ujs.js out, refresh the browser and try it again.

Also, take a look at the page source and see if jquery_ujs and jquery is referred to at the same time. If so, search in the source files for references to that jquery_ujs.

Worked for me, thanks guys.