# js.erb file is executing two times . Ruby on Rails - private_pub

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on `chating` module. For that I've used `private_pub gem`. In this module I have made three channels, but I can't mention all those here, because it'll show a very, very large page. So let's stick to one channel.

I click on a link having channel `"<%= subscribe_to "/conversations/send_invitation" %>"` and then `ajax` works and goes to `"conversations/send_invitation"` (only once - which is ok) and in my `"/conversations/send_invitation"` I have

```
def send_invitation
 @conversation = Conversation.new(conversation_params)
 respond_to do |format|
 format.js { render :layout => false }
 format.html
 end
end
```

and then in my `send_invitation.js.erb` file I've the following

```
<% publish_to "/conversations/send_invitation" do %>
var recipient_id = "<%=@conversation.recipient.id %>";
var current_temp_user = $("#current_temp_user").val();

if(recipient_id == current_temp_user){
console.log('here')
$("#invitation_div").html("<%=j(render :partial => '/restaurants/invitation')%>");
    card_modal = $('#invitation_card').modal();
    card_modal.modal('show');
}
<% end %>
```

Here is my `application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
// require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
// require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.raty
//= require private_pub
//= require_tree .
```

And the modal displays at `recipient side` (which is good).

Now the problem is that I can see two `modal` with the `same id` in my `firefox console/html`. And the `buttons` for `closing/submit` the `modal` also stopped working. Also the `console.log` in my `send_invitation.js.erb` file showed two time the `console.log` result, so it's clear that `js.erb` file is executing two times. But the point to note is that `ajax` ran one time only. I've wasted couple of hours on it and found only [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659209/rails-js-controller-being-called-twice-for-some-reason) which also didn't work for me, because when I remove either `jquery.js` or `jquery_ujs.js` it gives me errors

Comment: What does your server log say? Is the action `send_invitation` executed once or twice? Maybe you are subscribing to the channel twice? You can debug that in the developer console of the browser.

Comment: @coorasse no it's calling `send_invitation` only one time

Comment: so, can you see in the developers console if you subscribed twice to the channel?

Comment: I'm subscribed to two separate channels in the same page - is that any thing wrong

Comment: what is the response from the server when you execute the send_invitation method?

Comment: @ImranNaqvi can you tell what ID you are getting twice?

Comment: @uDaY `console.log('here')` in js.erb file is shown in firebug console two time . kindly have a look on the question

Comment: @ImranNaqvi, have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same right now and I hope you can help me out.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar please have a look on the my answer

Answer (score 0):

I could not found a solution , but i thought it'd be worth for someone to inform about the actual issue .
In my case the issue was that I was making two channels on the same page ,that's why it was making handshake with the thin server two times .

**Note** But in a generic case it can also happen if we included js file two times .

Comment: What does it mean to making to channels on the same page? Having <%= subscribe_to conversation_path(conversation) %> twice on the page and one conversation form or having <%= subscribe_to conversation_path(conversation) %> only once, but having two conversation forms? In my case it's a turbolinks issue for sure. If I do a full page reload everything works fine, but if I create the conversation.message after going to another the page of the app and then coming back it gets displayed more times (it saves only 1 message to the db, only having problem with displaying). Any guesses?

Comment: Imran, it seems I could solve this issue. Check out my answer!

Answer (score 0):

With `$(document).on('keydown', '.chatboxtextarea', function (event){....});` my message object was created only once, but got displayed several times based on how many times I returned to the page with turbolinks without full page reload.
To work around this in the js.erb file I added event.handled to check if partial has been already appended.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require chat
//= require refile
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require private_pub
//= require local_time
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree .
```

js file

```
 //submitting chat message (it's OUTSIDE $(document).on('page:change'..)
 //bind submit to document --> not affected by turbolinks
$(document).on('keydown', '.chatboxtextarea', function (event) {
  var id = $(this).data('cid');
  checkInputKey(event, $(this), id);
});

function checkInputKey(event, chatboxtextarea, conversation_id) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //checking if field is empty and submitting the form
    message = chatboxtextarea.val();
    message = message.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (message != '') {
      $('#conversation_form_' + conversation_id).submit();
    }
  }
}
```

html.erb form

```
<div class="chatboxinput">
  <%= form_for([@conversation, @message], :remote => true, :html => {id: "conversation_form_#{@conversation.id}"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "chatboxtextarea", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
  <% end %>
</div>
......
<%= subscribe_to conversation_path(@conversation) %>
```

_message.html.erb

```
<li class="<%= self_or_other(message) %>">
  <div class="chatboxmessagecontent">
    <p>
      <%= message.body %>
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

create.js.erb

```
<% publish_to @path do %>
  var id = "<%= @conversation.id %>";
  var chatbox = $(".chatboxcontent");
  var lastMessage = chatbox.children().last();

  //with this one message will be displayed only once
  if(event.handled !== true) {

    $message = $('<%= j render @message %>');
    chatbox.append($message);
    chatbox.scrollTop(chatbox[0].scrollHeight);

    //for displaying incoming and outgoing messages differently
    if(sender_id != receiver_id) {
        chatbox.children().last().removeClass("self").addClass("other");
        chatbox.scrollTop(chatbox[0].scrollHeight);
    }

    event.handled = true;
  };
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unbind method to remove unwanted/multiple calls to be executed with your events. This will do the trick. But reason behind the multiple calls is not yet clear.

```
$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this gem instead**

`gem "private_pub", :git => 'https://github.com/ryleto/private_pub.git'`